# Initializing a std::vector from a count and an element value with copies?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
vector<string> vec(10, string(10, 'a'));
```

My question is about the `string(10, 'a')`:

- Does it returns an anonymous variable?
- When the initialization statement over, the variable would be cleared?
- It would be copied to the vector?
- Have any differences from c++11 (at this point)?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, probably not.

Comment: it returns a temporary object which is destroyed when the initialization is completed. there's no variable, declared or undeclared, whatsoever.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant There is an [anonymous variable](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/814-anonymous-variables-and-objects/) created with expression scope.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The term "anonymous variable" is nowhere to be found in the C++11 standard. What you are referring to is called a "temporary object".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "anonymous variable" is an abuse of terminology (and arguably an oxymoron). You mean anonymous/temporary object, period.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You are welcome to call it a "temporary object" if you want. However, the OP called it an "anonymous variable", which is perfectly reasonable terminology. We aren't limited to language used in the C++11 standard.

Comment: @delnan No. It's perfectly normal English to use an adjective to modify a noun to include things that would be excluded only for that characteristic. For example, something cannot be a "car" if it's not a means of transportation, but it can be a "toy car" (roughly meaning "would be a car but for the fact it's a toy"). "Toy car" is not an oxymoron even though toys cannot be means of transportation and cars must be. This would be a variable but for the fact it's anonymous, so it's perfectly normal to call it an "anonymous variable".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz People are also free to call cars "horseless carriages", but it's still obscure terminology that hints at limited knowledge or confusion, so correcting it is perfectly reasonable. Programming is engineering and engineering lingo is distinct from day-to-day speech, for good reasons. Deviating from it is rarely useful, especially when it's unintentional as in this case.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz One could say that, but that's not the vocabulary usually used with C++ (and so is likely to lead to confusion).  In the usual C++ vocabulary, there is no such thing as an "anonymous variable".  There are, however, temporaries (rvalues).  (More general, the definition of a variable is the association of a name and an object.  So "anonymous variable" is an oxymoron.)

Comment: @delnan You're moving the goalposts. Arguing it's "obscure terminology" or "rarely useful" are much weaker claims than that it's "an abuse of terminology (and arguably an oxymoron)".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In C++ jargon, it's an abuse of terminology. Since you clarified you were assuming non-jargon English, I restated my point in the frame of using non-jargon to talk about things for which jargon exists.

Comment: @JamesKanze I honestly don't believe you. Are you really saying that a C++ programmer wouldn't understand "anonymous variable" to mean something that would be a variable but for the fact that it's anonymous? It was totally obvious to me, and my professional experience is almost entirely as a C++ programmer. Am I just much smarter than you guys? I don't think so. To be blunt, I believe you are intentionally misunderstanding a perfectly clear point for entirely pedantic purposes.

Comment: @delnan There is an ultra-specific definition of "variable" in the standard, but even that's not C++ jargon. At least in my experience, C++ programmers only rarely use the term "variable" in the way it is defined in the C++ standard, and that's pretty much only when discussing the standard. They use the term "variable" regularly in its ordinary computer science sense. Perhaps my experience radically differs from yours, but I doubt it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not saying he wouldn't understand it; I'm saying that he would find the vocabulary strange and unusual.  A nitpicker experienced in language theory would interpret it as an oxymoron.  But as I said: "you could say that"; it's just not the natural way of expressing things for someone experienced in the language.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't know how "variable" is defined in the standard. I too am talking about the common usage among C++ programmers. An ordinary CS variable is a *name* for something, that is all I need to object to "anonymous variable". Frankly, at this point I'm not sure any more what we're arguing about.

Comment: @delnan In common usage, a car is a means of transportation. Does that make "toy car" an oxymoron? An ordinary CS variable is not a name for something, it's a name for certain specific kinds of things. Files have names. Functions have names. They're not variables. An "anonymous variable" is a thing that would be a variable if it had a name, just like a "toy car" is a thing that would be a car if it wasn't a toy. We're arguing because you are making invalid arguments and I am pointing out that they are invalid.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The ordinary "computer" sense of "variable" is an association between a name and an object (or an entity which contains data).  The fact that something is named is what makes it a variable.  Having said that: your analogy with toy car vs. car is valid, and I don't think anyone would have trouble understanding "anonymous variable".  It's far enough from the usual vocabulary, however, that it's worth pointing out the "misuse" of the term to the OP.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "Toy car" is widely accepted and commonly used, and there's no good alternative really. I would also dissect it to mean "toy which resembles a car". OTOH "anonymous variable" is not established, so it is subject to greater scrutiny, and there are already perfectly good terms for what it intends to describe. (I wish SO would give us a "move to chat" button.)

Comment: @delnan The problem with your dissection is that "car" is the noun and "toy" is the adjective modifying it. And this particular English structure is used all the time in one offs, not just for established terms. There may be better ways to say it, but arguing that it's incorrect, an abuse of terminology, or otherwise anything worse than uncommon (though "anonymous variable" has 13,500 hits on google -- three times as many as "anonymous rat" or "yellow variable") is completely unjustified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it returns an anonymous variable?

No. It returns a **temporary object,** which is not a variable by-definition (§3.1/6 [basic]):

> A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than
>   a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name denotes
>   the reference or object.

<sub>Source: C++11 working draft [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)</sub>

> When the initialization statement over, the variable would be cleared?

No, it wouldn't. It has no name and at that point it's already destroyed anyway.

> It would be copied to the vector?

Yes, the temporary object would be copied into the vector, and then destroyed. This happens in principle; in practice, the compiler is allowed to optimize away the creation, copying and destruction of the temporary object as long as doing so doesn't affect observable behavior.

> Have any differences from c++11 (at this point)?

I can't tell for sure, but I can't recall any specific difference between C++98, C++03 and C++11 in this matter.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that in his case, the temporary will be copied 10 times into the vector.

Comment: the `temporary object` exist in the stack? or heap?

Comment: @pezy That's an operating system detail.

Comment: @remyabel some guys say: use `new` would put in heap, otherwise in stack? Is it right?

Comment: @pezy: The short answer is no, the long answer would start with "perhaps..." but not fit in a comment. As remyabel points out, the OS is really in charge and C++ just tells you how long the object lives, not where. ( "heap" => "until `delete`", "stack" => "until function returns", "global" => until program exits, "temporary" => until end of statement)

Comment: @pezy no, that's not right. The temporary object may be constructed anywhere the compiler/OS wishes. It is often stack-allocated. It might not always be. And anyway, "the stack" and "the heap" are platform-specific implementation details, and there's no point in discussing them unless we are talking about a specific implementation. The more precise, platform-agnostic wording (which is to be preferred for use in general discussion) is "automatic" and "dynamic" allocation (and storage duration), respectively.